# List view not showing complete Text

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-custom-view

[image: The original text is two lines more but it cut that part]I am developing an SMS application in which i have to save a received SMS in my application. I use a custom list view to save the SMS content, SMS sender and SMS date. This works completely fine when the incoming SMS is short i.e. 4 5 lines.
But the problem is that if the SMS is long i.e. more than 5 6 lines then the listview not showing full SMS. It shows first 4 5 lines but cut the next part of the SMS. I don't know what to do and completely stuck.

Here is my custom listview content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/product_icon"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:src="@drawable/personn"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"

    >

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"

    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_msgTO"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="Ahtesham"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#070B19"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="Ahtesham"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="#070B19"

        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_messageContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
        android:textColor="#585858"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:singleLine="true"

        android:text="Heloo How are you"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        />


</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

please look at id "message content" text view, the problem would be there i think

I am calling that main listview in the activity. xml code for main list view is

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/messageList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="@null"

    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp" />
```

and Finally I am fetching inbox messages in this list view

```
public void populateMessageList() {
fetchInboxMessages();

messageListAdapter = new SmsList(this,R.layout.smscontent, recordsStored);
messageList.setAdapter(messageListAdapter);
```

}

smscontent is the name of custom listview content
Please Help!!

Comment: can you share the screenshot

Comment: In which `Text View` `txt_messageContent` ?

Comment: @PhanVănLinh screeenshot added sir

Comment: @jaydroider yes exactly thats the textview

Comment: @ArslanAli Do you have any idea of max character length of your message ?

Comment: @jaydroider i didnot set any max length for the message but it automatically show 4 5 lines but not after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Attributes in your **`Text View`** for **txt_messageContent**.

```
android:maxLines="10"
android:lines="10"
android:singleLine="false"
```

**EDIT 1:**

Change this.

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

**EDIT 2:**

**Add this.**

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

**EDIT 3:**

Changed the `Layout` apply this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/product_icon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_msgTO"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:text="Ahtesham"
                android:textColor="#070B19"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
                android:text="Ahtesham"
                android:textColor="#070B19"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_messageContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Heloo How are you,Heloo How are you,Heloo How are you,Heloo How are you,Heloo How are you,Heloo How are youHeloo How are you,Heloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are you,Heloo How are you,Heloo How are you,Heloo How are you,Heloo How are you,Heloo How are youHeloo How are you,Heloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are you,Heloo How are you,Heloo How are you,Heloo How are you,Heloo How are you,Heloo How are youHeloo How are you,Heloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are you,Heloo How are you,Heloo How are you,Heloo How are you,Heloo How are you,Heloo How are youHeloo How are you,Heloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are you,Heloo How are you,Heloo How are you,Heloo How are you,Heloo How are you,Heloo How are youHeloo How are you,Heloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are youHeloo How are you"
            android:textColor="#585858"
            android:textSize="13sp" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Note:** You can change values of `maxLines and lines` as you want.

Comment: try change the values if you have more content let say change it from 10 to 50 and check.

Comment: no still now working, completely stuck with this strange problem

Comment: @ArslanAli Change height to `wrapcontent` and try.

Comment: @ArslanAli Remove `android:gravity="center_vertical"` and check. Instead give this `android:gravity="left"`.

Comment: @ArslanAli Check `EDIT 2` of my answer. sure it will work.

Comment: Don't be able to assume what is happening ! ! !

Comment: Same here don't understand whats the problem Sir

Comment: i noticed one thing that the SMS containing length greater than 140 is not showing

Comment: @ArslanAli Check `EDIT 3` last but not list. I have made some changes in width and height in main `Linear Layout`. Apply that to your XML.

Comment: It works FInally  You are a genious Thankyou for your time :)

Comment: Glad it works. Glad to help you . Cheers . Thanks for appreciation :) .

Answer (score 0):

try to by changing value of

```
 android:singleline="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code in my side and did some changes according your need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/product_icon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:padding="3dp"

        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"

        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"

            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_msgTO"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="Ahtesham"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#070B19"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:text="Ahtesham"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:textColor="#070B19"

                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_messageContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
            android:textColor="#585858"
            android:textSize="13sp"


            android:text="Heloo How are you I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service AtCmdFwd...
05-05 04:53:57.217 32404-32404/? I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service AtCmdFwd...
05-05 04:53:58.217 32404-32404/? I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service AtCmdFwd...I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service AtCmdFwd...
05-05 04:53:57.217 32404-32404/? I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service AtCmdFwd...
05-05 04:53:58.217 32404-32404/? I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service AtCmdFwd..."
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />


    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And this is the Screenshot for this..[image: screenshort]

Comment: But its not working when new SMS receives, i check it with pre defined text and it works but when SMS received and it save to db then this textview is not showing fully

Answer (score 0):

Change your `TextView` height to wrap_content 
and remove `android:singleline="true"`

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_messageContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
        android:textColor="#585858"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:text="Heloo How are you"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed            `android:singleLine="true"` fromtxt_messageContent and  *`txt_messageContent`* and it was working :-

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_messageContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="as \n as \n  asas\n as \n  asas\n as sas \n sasc \n as \n ass \n as \n aad \n as \n  add\n as \n add \n as \n"
        android:textColor="#585858"
        android:textSize="13sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add this `android:singleLine="false"` 
instead of `android:singleLine="true"` 
It will works...